# Discover unit tests selenium does not generate html reports

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

when runnning all tests using this command

> ```
> python -m unittest discover <tests directory> "test_*.py"
> ```

test are runned but html report are not generated any help please
i use this for html report :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main(testRunner=HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="test", title="test_004_report", open_in_browser=True))
```